# How to find replacement for this Blum-type hinge

Tags: cabinets, replacement, hinges

I have a broken hinge on a mirror cabinet. It is some kind of Blum-like hinge: it is connected to the bottom of the cabinet and then in the side to a door.

I can not seem to find such a hinge available.

Does anyone know how this would be called or where I can find it?

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Yeah, they're sold six at a time and come with a free medicine cabinet ;)

Comment: .... But isn't there anywhere to get just one of these?

Comment: If I had to guess, they're proprietary, or sold in lots numbering in the thousands. Someone might know otherwise... before this get closed as a *shop for me* question. Where's it broken? Is it not the one in the picture?

Comment: It doesn't stick to the base plate anymore? Drill a hole through the base plate and the bottom of the cabinet, and through-bolt it going though that funny looking hole.